# ImageButton closing div

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

This is my code :

```
<div runat="server" class="slide">
<img src="images/picto_detail.gif" onclick='<%# Eval("CampagneRappelId","hideshow(\"details{0}\")")%>' />
<div id='details<%# Eval("CampagneRappelId")%>' style="display: none;">
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DownloadPdf" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png"  />
</div>
```

The JS "hideshow(div)" is a simple function like :

```
function hideshow(which) {
    if (document.getElementById(which).style.display == "none")
        document.getElementById(which).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(which).style.display = "none"
}
```

But I have a problem with the asp:ImageButton. When I click on it, I have the code behind who download the file to the user computer, but also when the button is clicked, the div "details" is closed with a display:none... And I am not able to find why.

**EDIT :** I already tested something like this :

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("DownloadPdf").onclick = function (e) {

        if (e && e.stopPropagation && someCriteriaToStopBubbling === true) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        else if (someCriteriaToStopBubbling === true) {
            e = window.event;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what I've done to cancel the PostBack :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DownloadPdf" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then I put the ImageButton inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use an image to hide and show an div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#close').live('click',function(){
            $('#main').show();
            $('#login').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div style="float:right;"><a id="close">Close <img src="assets/close.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I know, but my hide/show function is ok. It's when I click on the asp:ImageButton the div who normally needs to stay on the screen disappear.
In my opinion it's the postback when user click on the button.